# C# LINQ GroupJoin skip item

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following code

```
  var profilesWithMailLists = profilesWithCf.GroupJoin(
               profile2Maillist,
               p => p.SqlId,
               p2l => p2l.ProfileId,
               (p, mailLists) =>
               {
                   var p2lmongo = mailLists.Select<TProfile2MailList, Profile2MailList>(p2l =>
                   {
                       return new Profile2MailList
                        {
                            MailListId = p2l.MailListId,
                            Status = p2l.Status,
                            SubscriptionDate = p2l.SubscriptionDate
                        };
                   });
                   p.MailLists = p2lmongo.ToArray();
                   return p;
               });
```

Is it possible to skip iteration and returning of profile if `p2lmongo` collection will contain 0 elements ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate through `profilesWithMailLists` *until* there is a `p2lmongo` with 0 elements? Or do you want to *filter* these out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GroupBy` and a `Join` instead of `GroupJoin`.

Some code to illustrate (not tested or type-checked):

```
var profilesWithMailListsAlt =
    profilesWithCf.Join(
        profile2Maillist.GroupBy(p2l => p2l.ProfileId),
        p => p.SqlId,
        p2lgroup => p2lgroup.Key,
        (p, mailListGroup) =>
        {
            var p2lmongo = mailListGroup.Select<TProfile2MailList, Profile2MailList>(p2l =>
            {
                return new Profile2MailList
                {
                    MailListId = p2l.MailListId,
                    Status = p2l.Status,
                    SubscriptionDate = p2l.SubscriptionDate
                };
            });
            p.MailLists = p2lmongo.ToArray();
            return p;
        });
```

If that still doesn't do what you want, try explicitly excluding empty groups by changing

```
profile2Maillist.GroupBy(p2l => p2l.ProfileId)
```

to

```
profile2Maillist.GroupBy(p2l => p2l.ProfileId).Where(group => group.Any())
```

Just shooting from  the hip here.